# can't install setuptools for python3 on RedHat

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

My system is RedHat 7.0 + python3.4

There is no package with yum install.

So i use

```
python3 ez_setup.py
```

to install Setuptools.

But there are some errors showed up

```
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-8.2.1.zip
Extracting in /tmp/tmpzu9sj75k
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ez_setup.py", line 332, in <module>
sys.exit(main())
File "ez_setup.py", line 329, in main
return _install(archive, _build_install_args(options))
File "ez_setup.py", line 51, in _install
with archive_context(archive_filename):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/contextlib.py", line 59, in __enter__
return next(self.gen)
File "ez_setup.py", line 101, in archive_context
archive.extractall()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/zipfile.py", line 1240, in extractall
self.extract(zipinfo, path, pwd)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/zipfile.py", line 1228, in extract
return self._extract_member(member, path, pwd)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/zipfile.py", line 1290, in _extract_member
with self.open(member, pwd=pwd) as source, \
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/zipfile.py", line 1210, in open
close_fileobj=not self._filePassed)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/zipfile.py", line 651, in __init__
self._decompressor = _get_decompressor(self._compress_type)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/zipfile.py", line 614, in _get_decompressor
return zlib.decompressobj(-15)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decompressobj'
```

why is that so hard to install pip3....
Can anyone help me?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I used this to install

wget https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py -O - | python

I found this if it can help you :
http://showmedo.com/videotutorials/video?name=2070000

Comment: Do I have to use  wget https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py -O - | python3.4 ??  since i want to install on python3.4

Comment: no I guess there is some thing called python brew to switch between python versions. I am not exactly sure about the details of it.

Comment: Here I found something on python brew, how to install and switch between versions                                   http://www.howopensource.com/2011/05/how-to-install-and-manage-different-versions-of-python-in-linux/